# Variables globales python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en python usando el patrón MVC, por tanto tengo un modelo, controlador y vista. Desde uno de los controladores, accedo a un controlador que tiene una variable global con información y una función para extraer esa información, el problema es que para hacerlo, necesito que esa función tenga como parámetro self, la pregunta es ¿Cómo llamo a esa función desde el controlador? Por ejemplo, tengo estos directorios y archivos:

```
/Controller
    /test.py
/Model
    /frutas.py
```

Y el código es el siguiente:
frutas.py:

```
class frutas:
    frutas = [
        "Manzana",
        "Pera",
        "Naranja"
    ]

    def getFrutas(self):
        return self.frutas

    def suma(a,b):
        return a+b
```

test.py:

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
               os.path.dirname(__file__),
               os.pardir))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)

from Model.frutas import frutas

print(frutas.suma(5,3))
print(frutas.getFrutas())
```

En este caso si ejecuto test.py, la función suma no tiene problemas, sin embargo, la función getFrutas falla porque dice que necesita un argumento, pero claro, no puedo pasarle la referencia a la clase frutas, no?
Por favor no me mateis si he cometido algún fallo tonto, soy nuevo en python jajaj, gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error en la definición del método "suma" en la clase frutas.

Deberías incluir self como el primer parámetro en el método suma para que sea un método de instancia.

El codigo en frutas.py:

```
def suma(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

...y en test.py la instancias

```
from Model.frutas import frutas


frutas_instancia = frutas()

print(frutas_instancia.getFrutas())
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias.